# I cannot connect to a port that is already open in my firewall

Tags: iptables, port, telnet

I have tried to open port 80

```
[root@rhel7 docker]# firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp --permanent
success
[root@rhel7 docker]# firewall-cmd --reload
success
[root@rhel7 docker]# iptables-save | grep 80
-A POSTROUTING_ZONES -o eno16780032 -g POST_public
-A PREROUTING_ZONES -i eno16780032 -g PRE_public
-A PREROUTING_ZONES -i eno16780032 -g PRE_public
-A FORWARD_IN_ZONES -i eno16780032 -g FWDI_public
-A FORWARD_OUT_ZONES -o eno16780032 -g FWDO_public
-A INPUT_ZONES -i eno16780032 -g IN_public
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
```

but when I try to use

```
netstat -an
```

It didnt show up port 80 are listening. When I try to telnet the port, it shows the following

```
[root@rhel7 docker]# telnet localhost 80
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
```

Anyways to resolve?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you run any program that actually listens on that port?

Comment: no...I just set up this new machine, any configuration I should do?

Comment: What do you expect to answer on this port? HTTP server maybe?

Comment: You need to run any application that occupies the port 80 ex a webserver. If the webserver starts, you can see listen on netstat -an command.

Comment: The firewall does not affect `netstat` output (ie. whether programs can listen). It just controls whether anyone can connect to the listener.

Answer (score 2):

Having a port open on firewall and having a program listening on that port are two different things.

I think `netstat` shows ports being listened on regardless of firewall settings. There is nothing listening on `80/tcp` port, therefore your `telnet` cannot connect.

EDIT, NOTE: I really doubt your firewall blocks connection from `localhost` to `localhost` by default. If I'm right and you had some program listening then your `telnet localhost 80` would succeed even without your initial `firewall-cmd` invocation.

---

On my Debian `sudo nestat -an` shows some ports in listening state, but it doesn't tell which programs listen. I can list all listening programs by

```
sudo lsof -i TCP -s TCP:LISTEN
```

---

Not knowing (yet) what sort of service you expect to answer on `80/tcp` port, I take a guess it is http server. Either there is none installed at all or the one you have has not been started. There is a number of them to pick. E.g. it may or may not be `httpd`. Try

```
sudo service httpd status
```

You may see [this guide](https://linuxconfig.org/apache-webserver-httpd-service-installation-on-redhat-7-linux) for some start with `httpd` on RHEL7.